# how can I find the all the numeric characters in a specific column in a metrix and printing them?

Tags: r

how can I  find the all the numeric characters in a specific column in a metrix and printing them? 
for example this list:

```
dat <- matrix(c(1,"a","b", 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, 
               dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"), 
                               c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3"))) 
dat 
     C.1  C.2  C.3 
row1 "1"  "a"  "b" 
row2 "11" "12" "13"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep`.

```
> grep("\\d+", c(dat), value=TRUE)
[1] "1"  "11" "12" "13"
```

If you want the location of each element in the matrix they come from, then you can use:

```
> num <- grep("\\d+", c(dat), value=TRUE)
> positions <- sapply(num, function(x) which(dat == x, arr.ind = TRUE))
> rownames(positions) <- c("row", "col")
> positions
    1 11 12 13
row 1  2  2  2
col 1  1  2  3
```

It tells you number 1 is in row 1, col 1 in matrix `dat`. Number 11 is in row 2, col 1 in `dat`.

Comment: `which` has the argument `arr.ind` which you can set to `TRUE`: `which(array(grepl("\\d+", c(dat)),dim(dat)),T)`

Comment: @Onyambu you're rigth, I did use `arr.ind` but I took the long way

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a vector, and then remove all `NAs`. This works because the conversion puts non-numeric data to `NA`.

```
v <- as.numeric(dat)
v[!is.na(v)]

[1]  1 11 12 13
```